# What would be the equivalent code in reactjs for this angularjs code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a website which was based on angularjs. Now I want to convert few snippets into reactjs and I never used angular so obviously I'm having problem understanding few of the codes written in angularjs. I understand some of the code written here as it is used to save a post and show error when it's not saved. but i don't understand $scope and how to convert this piece of code to react. I hope someone could help me

```
$scope.savepost=function(){
    $scope.postdata={}
    $scope.postdata['postTitle']=$scope.postTitle
    $scope.postdata['postDescription']=$scope.postDescription
    console.log($scope.postId)
    if($scope.postId==null){
        return $http.post('/api/saveposts',$scope.postdata).then(function(response){
            if(response.status==200){
                $scope.postId=response.data;
                toaster.pop('success','post saved successfully!')                    
            }else{                
                toaster.pop('danger','An error has occured while saving the post. Please try again')                                        
            }
        });
    }else{
        $scope.postdata['postId']=$scope.postId        
        return $http.post('/api/updateposts',$scope.postdata).then(function(response,status){
            if(response.status==200){
                toaster.pop('success','post saved successfully!')                                        
            }else{
                toaster.pop('danger','An error has occured while updating the post. Please try again')                                                            
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello UbuntuNewb! welcome to Stack Overflow. The point of the sight is to create a library of knowledge, without any "debug/write my code" questions. In light of that, could you please tell us specifically what your problem is, and what you have tried?

Comment: there is this website which is written in angularjs. the above code is a simple piece of code which I extracted from the wesbite and it basically is written to save the post. After reading the post, I can understand the code what it's doing but I can't understand what all those syntaxes mean so I want equivalent code of the above piece of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would look something like this:

```
// destructure postId from props
const SomeFormComponent = ({ postId }) => {

  const [postState, setPostState] = useState({title: '', description: ''})

  /*
  This example assumes you've set your input values to postState
  */

  const handleRequest= async (url) => {
    // copy all the input values set to state
    const post = {...postState}
    // this will be passed into fetch
    const request = {
      method: 'POST'
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }

    if(postId != null) post['id'] = postId

    try {
      // use fetch, stringify json
      const response = await fetch(url, { ...request, body: JSON.stringify(post )})
      // handle json response
      const data = await response.json()
      if (data.status == 200) {
        toaster.pop('success', 'post saved successfully!')
        /*
           Do something with the response
        */
      } else {
        toaster.pop('danger', 'An error has occurred while updating the post. Please try again')
      }
    } catch(ex) => {
      console.error(ex.stack)
      toaster.pop('danger', 'An error has occurred while updating the post. Please try again')
    }
  }



  const handlePost = () => {
    if(postId == null) {
        return handleRequest('/api/savepost')
    }
    return handleRequest('/api/updatepost')

  }
  return (<button onClick={handlePost}>Save</button>)
}
```

Comment: I think if postId==null, then it won't delete the post.id but it will assign a new post.id and if it already exists then it will update the existing post using that post.id, right?

Comment: Are you getting a postId from your response? If so, you should only worry about submitting a postId with a request if you're PUT'ing or PATCh'ing. Your database should generate an ID on creation of the record.

Comment: and you didn't call api /savepost at all. I think it should be called first when there is no id matching it. If the id exists then we should call the api/updatepost, no?